# Family inbox in G Suite Groups

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

I'm trying to create a simple family group that receives mail sent to the address family@example.com and forwards it to all my members of my family. I only want this group to be accessible from the outside via the mail address family@example.com and don't want people to be able to see who's inside the group. This used to be simple but since the transition from Google Apps to G Suite, this has become a lot more complicated.

Could somebody point me in the right direction as to which settings I need to configure exactly in the access panel of a group's settings page to achieve my goal?

Comment: Are you using the legacy free edition of G Suite?

Comment: @rahi The €4 a month version

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want an *email list*. This is part of the *Google Groups for Business* offering. [It is not available in the (legacy) free editions of Google Apps.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120)

If you have an eligible G Suite subscription, you can enable the Groups for Business service in the G Suite control panel.

Then follow [Google's guide](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/groups/get-started/#section-3-1), make sure you create an *email list*.

In short, the steps are:

1. Go to http://groups.google.com
2. Click *My Groups*, and *Switch organization view to example.com* (so that your group is not listed publicly)
3. Click *Create group*, and fill in the form
4. Click *Direct add members* and add the email addresses that will be part of the list
5. Click *Add* (not *Send invites*) if you know these people and are sure they want to be part of the list

https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/groups/get-started/#section-3-1